# Extract all the character between space after a keyword in python dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a string contains "order". The order doesn't follow any format as it contains special character. I want to extract order number with special character with it. The idea is to extract all the character after the keyword "order" till the next space in one query.

```
      message                                  Model
order 769707-134432 has reached EARLY.       LG
Delivered : order 1765412456                 Samsung
No New Updates : order RS1765123404          Sony
order #769707-41213-4355 is EARLY            Dell
No New Updates : order 3FA1765404            Samsung
order #76923407 has reached EARLY            LG
No New Updates : order R-176543123           Sony
Recheduled : order 100251283_415731301       Sony
order #9T_0312330 delivered                  Dell
order #000090223532 has arrived at pickup.   LG
```

I required output should be

```
   message                                   order               Model
order 769707-134432 has reached EARLY       769707-134432        LG
Delivered : order 1765412456                1765412456           Samsung
No New Updates : order RS1765123404         RS1765123404         Sony
order #769707-41213-4355 is EARLY           769707-41213-4355    Dell
No New Updates : order 3FA1765404           3FA1765404           Samsung
order #76923407 has reached EARLY           76923407             LG
No New Updates : order R-176543123          R-176543123          Sony
Recheduled : order 100251283_415731301      1002283_4157301      Sony
order #9T_0312330 delivered                 9T_0312330           Dell
order #000090223532 has arrived at pickup   000090223532         LG
```

When I tried using Regex, I am getting  `#000090223532 has`,  `769707-`, `3FA`

Comment: "The idea is to extract all the character after the keyword "order" till the next space in one query." "When I tried using Regex," Okay, and *what regex did you use* to represent that rule?

Comment: please include your code.

Comment: I used order\s+\w+\W+\S . However this doesn't fetch 769707-134432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the cleanest way would be to use `str.extract`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df['order'] = df['message'].str.extract(r'order\s+\#?(\S+)')
print(df)
```

This yields

```
                                      message    model                order
0      order 769707-134432 has reached EARLY.       LG        769707-134432
1                Delivered : order 1765412456  Samsung           1765412456
2         No New Updates : order RS1765123404     Sony         RS1765123404
3           order #769707-41213-4355 is EARLY     Dell    769707-41213-4355
4           No New Updates : order 3FA1765404  Samsung           3FA1765404
5           order #76923407 has reached EARLY       LG             76923407
6          No New Updates : order R-176543123     Sony          R-176543123
7      Recheduled : order 100251283_415731301     Sony  100251283_415731301
8                 order #9T_0312330 delivered     Dell           9T_0312330
9  order #000090223532 has arrived at pickup.       LG         000090223532
```

See a demo for the expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pJkqNY/1).

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.replace` we can try:

```
data["order"]= data["message"].str.replace("^.*\border #?(\S+)\b.*$", "\1")
```

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't seem to yield what OP needs.